# How to sum linked entities

Tags: sql, oracle, linq, entity-framework, sum

I have my database as follows.
[image: Database scheme]
Title(id,...)
BuildIndicators(id, title_id, build_indicator_type)
BuildIndicatorValues(id, build_indicator_id, build_indicator_value_type, value)

Main object is Title.
Title has some BuildIndicators. Relation beetwen Title and BuildIndicators are one title to many BuildIndicators(id, title_id, build_indicator_type).
BuildIndicators linked whith BuildIndicatorValues as one BuildIndicator to many BuildIndicatorValues(id, build_indicator_id, build_indicator_value_type, value).
Here is generated classes:

```
public partial class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BuildIndicator> BuildIndicators { get; set; }

    public Title()
    {
        this.BuildIndicators = new HashSet<BuildIndicator>();
    }
}

public partial class BuildIndicator : BaseHistoryEntity
{
    public BuildIndicator()
    {
        this.BuildIndicatorValues = new HashSet<BuildIndicatorValue>();
    }

    public string Remark { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TitleId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BuildIndicatorTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BuildIndicatorClassifierId { get; set; }

    public virtual Title Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BuildIndicatorValue> BuildIndicatorValues { get; set; }
    public virtual BuildIndicatorType BuildIndicatorType { get; set; }
    public virtual BuildIndicatorClassifier BuildIndicatorClassifier { get; set; }
}

public partial class BuildIndicatorValue : BaseHistoryEntity
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BuildIndicatorId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> QuarterNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BuildIndicatorValueTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual BuildIndicator BuildIndicator { get; set; }
    public virtual BuildIndicatorValueType BuildIndicatorValueType { get; set; }
}
```

How I can sum BuildIndicatorValues for one title?
For example:
    `var sum = title.Sum(bi->bi.BuildIndicator.BuildIndicatorValues(....) ?`

I have write this code to resolve my issue:

```
        var query = from title in titleService.GetObjectContext()
            from bi in title.BuildIndicators
            from biv in bi.BuildIndicatorValues
            group biv by new {bi.BuildIndicatorType, bi.BuildIndicatorClassifier.FinancingSource, biv.Year} into yearGroup
            orderby yearGroup.Key.BuildIndicatorType.Name, yearGroup.Key.FinancingSource.Name, yearGroup.Key.Year
                    select new KiLfItem
                    {
                        BuildIndicatorType = new NameValue(){Id = yearGroup.Key.BuildIndicatorType.Id, Name = yearGroup.Key.BuildIndicatorType.Name},
                        FinancingSource = new NameValue() { Id = yearGroup.Key.FinancingSource.Id, Name = yearGroup.Key.FinancingSource.Name},
                        Year = yearGroup.Key.Year,
                        Sum = yearGroup.Sum(v => v.Value)
                    };
```

but when EF translate this to sql it looks like this

SELECT
"Project2"."C5" AS "C1",
"Project2"."C3" AS "C2",
"Project2"."NAME" AS "NAME",
"Project2"."C4" AS "C3",
"Project2"."NAME1" AS "NAME1",
"Project2"."C2" AS "C4",
"Project2"."C1" AS "C5"
FROM ( SELECT
    "GroupBy1"."A1" AS "C1",
    "GroupBy1"."K1" AS "C2",
    "GroupBy1"."K47" AS "NAME",
    "GroupBy1"."K51" AS "C3",
    "GroupBy1"."K92" AS "NAME1",
    "GroupBy1"."K96" AS "C4",
    1 AS "C5"
    FROM ( SELECT
        "Project1"."C1" AS "K1",
        "Project1"."NAME" AS "K2",
        "Project1"."CREATE_DATE" AS "K3",
        "Project1"."DELETE_DATE" AS "K4",
        "Project1"."C2" AS "K5",
        "Project1"."C3" AS "K6",
        "Project1"."C4" AS "K7",
        "Project1"."C5" AS "K8",
        "Project1"."C6" AS "K9",
        "Project1"."C7" AS "K10",
        "Project1"."C8" AS "K11",
        "Project1"."C9" AS "K12",
        "Project1"."C10" AS "K13",
        "Project1"."C11" AS "K14",
        "Project1"."C12" AS "K15",
        "Project1"."C13" AS "K16",
        "Project1"."C14" AS "K17",
        "Project1"."C15" AS "K18",
        "Project1"."C16" AS "K19",
        "Project1"."C17" AS "K20",
        "Project1"."C18" AS "K21",
        "Project1"."C19" AS "K22",
        "Project1"."C20" AS "K23",
        "Project1"."C21" AS "K24",
        "Project1"."C22" AS "K25",
        "Project1"."C23" AS "K26",
        "Project1"."C24" AS "K27",
        "Project1"."C25" AS "K28",
        "Project1"."C26" AS "K29",
        "Project1"."C27" AS "K30",
        "Project1"."C28" AS "K31",
        "Project1"."C29" AS "K32",
        "Project1"."C30" AS "K33",
        "Project1"."C31" AS "K34",
        "Project1"."C32" AS "K35",
        "Project1"."C33" AS "K36",
        "Project1"."C34" AS "K37",
        "Project1"."C35" AS "K38",
        "Project1"."C36" AS "K39",
        "Project1"."C37" AS "K40",
        "Project1"."C38" AS "K41",
        "Project1"."C39" AS "K42",
        "Project1"."C40" AS "K43",
        "Project1"."C41" AS "K44",
        "Project1"."C42" AS "K45",
        "Project1"."C43" AS "K46",
        "Project1"."NAME1" AS "K47",
        "Project1"."CREATE_DATE1" AS "K48",
        "Project1"."DELETE_DATE1" AS "K49",
        "Project1"."C44" AS "K50",
        "Project1"."C45" AS "K51",
        "Project1"."C46" AS "K52",
        "Project1"."C47" AS "K53",
        "Project1"."C48" AS "K54",
        "Project1"."C49" AS "K55",
        "Project1"."C50" AS "K56",
        "Project1"."C51" AS "K57",
        "Project1"."C52" AS "K58",
        "Project1"."C53" AS "K59",
        "Project1"."C54" AS "K60",
        "Project1"."C55" AS "K61",
        "Project1"."C56" AS "K62",
        "Project1"."C57" AS "K63",
        "Project1"."C58" AS "K64",
        "Project1"."C59" AS "K65",
        "Project1"."C60" AS "K66",
        "Project1"."C61" AS "K67",
        "Project1"."C62" AS "K68",
        "Project1"."C63" AS "K69",
        "Project1"."C64" AS "K70",
        "Project1"."C65" AS "K71",
        "Project1"."C66" AS "K72",
        "Project1"."C67" AS "K73",
        "Project1"."C68" AS "K74",
        "Project1"."C69" AS "K75",
        "Project1"."C70" AS "K76",
        "Project1"."C71" AS "K77",
        "Project1"."C72" AS "K78",
        "Project1"."C73" AS "K79",
        "Project1"."C74" AS "K80",
        "Project1"."C75" AS "K81",
        "Project1"."C76" AS "K82",
        "Project1"."C77" AS "K83",
        "Project1"."C78" AS "K84",
        "Project1"."C79" AS "K85",
        "Project1"."C80" AS "K86",
        "Project1"."C81" AS "K87",
        "Project1"."C82" AS "K88",
        "Project1"."C83" AS "K89",
        "Project1"."C84" AS "K90",
        "Project1"."C85" AS "K91",
        "Project1"."NAME2" AS "K92",
        "Project1"."CREATE_DATE2" AS "K93",
        "Project1"."DELETE_DATE2" AS "K94",
        "Project1"."C86" AS "K95",
        "Project1"."C87" AS "K96",
        "Project1"."C88" AS "K97",
        "Project1"."C89" AS "K98",
        "Project1"."C90" AS "K99",
        "Project1"."C91" AS "K100",
        "Project1"."C92" AS "K101",
        "Project1"."C93" AS "K102",
        "Project1"."C94" AS "K103",
        "Project1"."C95" AS "K104",
        "Project1"."C96" AS "K105",
        "Project1"."C97" AS "K106",
        "Project1"."C98" AS "K107",
        "Project1"."C99" AS "K108",
        "Project1"."C100" AS "K109",
        "Project1"."C101" AS "K110",
        "Project1"."C102" AS "K111",
        "Project1"."C103" AS "K112",
        "Project1"."C104" AS "K113",
        "Project1"."C105" AS "K114",
        "Project1"."C106" AS "K115",
        "Project1"."C107" AS "K116",
        "Project1"."C108" AS "K117",
        "Project1"."C109" AS "K118",
        "Project1"."C110" AS "K119",
        "Project1"."C111" AS "K120",
        "Project1"."C112" AS "K121",
        "Project1"."C113" AS "K122",
        "Project1"."C114" AS "K123",
        "Project1"."C115" AS "K124",
        "Project1"."C116" AS "K125",
        "Project1"."C117" AS "K126",
        "Project1"."C118" AS "K127",
        "Project1"."C119" AS "K128",
        "Project1"."C120" AS "K129",
        "Project1"."C121" AS "K130",
        "Project1"."C122" AS "K131",
        "Project1"."C123" AS "K132",
        "Project1"."C124" AS "K133",
        "Project1"."C125" AS "K134",
        "Project1"."C126" AS "K135",
        "Project1"."C127" AS "K136",
        SUM("Project1"."VALUE") AS "A1"
        FROM ( SELECT
            "Filter1"."VALUE" AS "VALUE",
             CAST( "Filter1"."YEAR" AS number(10,0)) AS "C1",
            "Extent5"."NAME" AS "NAME",
            "Extent5"."CREATE_DATE" AS "CREATE_DATE",
            "Extent5"."DELETE_DATE" AS "DELETE_DATE",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent5"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE '0X0X4X' END AS "C2",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent5"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent5"."ID" AS number(10,0)) END AS "C3",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent5"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent5"."ENTITY_ID" AS number(10,0))  END AS "C4", 
            CASE WHEN ("Extent5"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent5"."CREATOR" AS number(10,0))  END AS "C5",
            NULL AS "C6",
            NULL AS "C7",
            NULL AS "C8",
            NULL AS "C9",
            NULL AS "C10",
            NULL AS "C11",
            NULL AS "C12",
            NULL AS "C13",
            NULL AS "C14",
            NULL AS "C15",
            NULL AS "C16",
            NULL AS "C17",
            NULL AS "C18",
            NULL AS "C19",
            NULL AS "C20",
            NULL AS "C21",
            NULL AS "C22",
            NULL AS "C23",
            NULL AS "C24",
            NULL AS "C25",
            NULL AS "C26",
            NULL AS "C27",
            NULL AS "C28",
            NULL AS "C29",
            NULL AS "C30",
            NULL AS "C31",
            NULL AS "C32",
            NULL AS "C33",
            NULL AS "C34",
            NULL AS "C35",
            NULL AS "C36",
            NULL AS "C37",
            NULL AS "C38",
            NULL AS "C39",
            NULL AS "C40",
            NULL AS "C41",
            NULL AS "C42",
            NULL AS "C43",
            "Extent6"."NAME" AS "NAME1",
            "Extent6"."CREATE_DATE" AS "CREATE_DATE1",
            "Extent6"."DELETE_DATE" AS "DELETE_DATE1",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent6"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE '0X0X5X' END AS "C44",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent6"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent6"."ID" AS number(10,0)) END AS "C45",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent6"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent6"."ENTITY_ID" AS number(10,0)) END AS "C46",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent6"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent6"."CREATOR" AS number(10,0)) END AS "C47",
            NULL AS "C48",
            NULL AS "C49",
            NULL AS "C50",
            NULL AS "C51",
            NULL AS "C52",
            NULL AS "C53",
            NULL AS "C54",
            NULL AS "C55",
            NULL AS "C56",
            NULL AS "C57",
            NULL AS "C58",
            NULL AS "C59",
            NULL AS "C60",
            NULL AS "C61",
            NULL AS "C62",
            NULL AS "C63",
            NULL AS "C64",
            NULL AS "C65",
            NULL AS "C66",
            NULL AS "C67",
            NULL AS "C68",
            NULL AS "C69",
            NULL AS "C70",
            NULL AS "C71",
            NULL AS "C72",
            NULL AS "C73",
            NULL AS "C74",
            NULL AS "C75",
            NULL AS "C76",
            NULL AS "C77",
            NULL AS "C78",
            NULL AS "C79",
            NULL AS "C80",
            NULL AS "C81",
            NULL AS "C82",
            NULL AS "C83",
            NULL AS "C84",
            NULL AS "C85",
            "Extent8"."NAME" AS "NAME2",
            "Extent8"."CREATE_DATE" AS "CREATE_DATE2",
            "Extent8"."DELETE_DATE" AS "DELETE_DATE2",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent8"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE '0X0X6X' END AS "C86",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent8"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent8"."ID" AS number(10,0)) END AS "C87",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent8"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent8"."ENTITY_ID" AS number(10,0)) END AS "C88",
            CASE WHEN ("Extent8"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent8"."CREATOR" AS number(10,0)) END AS "C89",
            NULL AS "C90",
            NULL AS "C91",
            NULL AS "C92",
            NULL AS "C93",
            NULL AS "C94",
            NULL AS "C95",
            NULL AS "C96",
            NULL AS "C97",
            NULL AS "C98",
            NULL AS "C99",
            NULL AS "C100",
            NULL AS "C101",
            NULL AS "C102",
            NULL AS "C103",
            NULL AS "C104",
            NULL AS "C105",
            NULL AS "C106",
            NULL AS "C107",
            NULL AS "C108",
            NULL AS "C109",
            NULL AS "C110",
            NULL AS "C111",
            NULL AS "C112",
            NULL AS "C113",
            NULL AS "C114",
            NULL AS "C115",
            NULL AS "C116",
            NULL AS "C117",
            NULL AS "C118",
            NULL AS "C119",
            NULL AS "C120",
            NULL AS "C121",
            NULL AS "C122",
            NULL AS "C123",
            NULL AS "C124",
            NULL AS "C125",
            NULL AS "C126",
            NULL AS "C127"
            FROM       (SELECT "Extent1"."ID" AS "ID1", "Extent1"."TITLE_NUMBER" AS "TITLE_NUMBER", "Extent1"."IS_DRAFT" AS "IS_DRAFT", "Extent1"."REGISTRY_DATE" AS "REGISTRY_DATE", "Extent1"."LAST_MODIFIED" AS "LAST_MODIFIED", "Extent1"."LAST_MODIFIED_BY" AS "LAST_MODIFIED_BY", "Extent1"."TITLE_STATUS_ID" AS "TITLE_STATUS_ID", "Extent1"."BUILD_TYPE_ID" AS "BUILD_TYPE_ID", "Extent1"."OKVED_ID" AS "OKVED_ID", "Extent1"."DELIVERY_DATE" AS "DELIVERY_DATE", "Extent1"."TITLE_BUILD_CHARACTERISTIC_ID" AS "TITLE_BUILD_CHARACTERISTIC_ID", "Extent1"."TITLE_TYPE_ID" AS "TITLE_TYPE_ID", "Extent1"."BASE_PRICE_ID" AS "BASE_PRICE_ID", "Extent1"."KOSGU" AS "KOSGU", "Extent1"."ENTITY_ID" AS "ENTITY_ID1", "Extent1"."CREATE_DATE" AS "CREATE_DATE1", "Extent1"."DELETE_DATE" AS "DELETE_DATE1", "Extent1"."CREATOR" AS "CREATOR1", "Extent1"."VPP_ID" AS "VPP_ID", "Extent1"."PARENT_ID" AS "PARENT_ID", "Extent1"."OWNER_ENTITY_ID" AS "OWNER_ENTITY_ID", "Extent2"."ID" AS "ID2", "Extent2"."REMARK" AS "REMARK", "Extent2"."TITLE_ID" AS "TITLE_ID", "Extent2"."BUILD_INDICATOR_TYPE_ID" AS "BUILD_INDICATOR_TYPE_ID", "Extent2"."BUILD_INDICATOR_CLASSIFIER_ID" AS "BUILD_INDICATOR_CLASSIFIER_ID", "Extent2"."ENTITY_ID" AS "ENTITY_ID2", "Extent2"."CREATE_DATE" AS "CREATE_DATE2", "Extent2"."DELETE_DATE" AS "DELETE_DATE2", "Extent2"."CREATOR" AS "CREATOR2", "Extent3"."ID" AS "ID3", "Extent3"."YEAR" AS "YEAR", "Extent3"."VALUE" AS "VALUE", "Extent3"."BUILD_INDICATOR_ID" AS "BUILD_INDICATOR_ID", "Extent3"."QUARTER_NUMBER" AS "QUARTER_NUMBER", "Extent3"."BUILD_INDICATOR_VALUE_TYPE_ID" AS "BUILD_INDICATOR_VALUE_TYPE_ID", "Extent3"."ENTITY_ID" AS "ENTITY_ID3", "Extent3"."CREATE_DATE" AS "CREATE_DATE3", "Extent3"."DELETE_DATE" AS "DELETE_DATE3", "Extent3"."CREATOR" AS "CREATOR3"
                FROM   "STROY"."TITLE" "Extent1"
                INNER JOIN "STROY"."BUILD_INDICATOR" "Extent2" ON ( CAST( "Extent1"."ID" AS number(10,0))) = ( CAST( "Extent2"."TITLE_ID" AS number(10,0)))
                INNER JOIN "STROY"."BUILD_INDICATOR_VALUE" "Extent3" ON ( CAST( "Extent2"."ID" AS number(10,0))) = ( CAST( "Extent3"."BUILD_INDICATOR_ID" AS number(10,0)))
                WHERE (((1 = ( CAST( "Extent1"."TITLE_TYPE_ID" AS number(10,0)))) OR (2 = ( CAST( "Extent1"."TITLE_TYPE_ID" AS number(10,0))))) AND ((2 = ( CAST( "Extent2"."BUILD_INDICATOR_TYPE_ID" AS number(10,0)))) OR (3 = ( CAST( "Extent2"."BUILD_INDICATOR_TYPE_ID" AS number(10,0))))) AND (0 <> ( CAST( "Extent3"."YEAR" AS number(10,0)))) AND (1 = ( CAST( "Extent3"."BUILD_INDICATOR_VALUE_TYPE_ID" AS number(10,0))))) ) "Filter1"
            LEFT OUTER JOIN "STROY"."BUILD_INDICATOR_CLASSIFIER" "Extent4" ON ( CAST( "Filter1"."BUILD_INDICATOR_CLASSIFIER_ID" AS number(10,0))) = ( CAST( "Extent4"."ID" AS number(10,0)))
            LEFT OUTER JOIN "STROY"."TITLE_TYPE" "Extent5" ON ( CAST( "Filter1"."TITLE_TYPE_ID" AS number(10,0))) = ( CAST( "Extent5"."ID" AS number(10,0)))
            LEFT OUTER JOIN "STROY"."BUILD_INDICATOR_TYPE" "Extent6" ON ( CAST( "Filter1"."BUILD_INDICATOR_TYPE_ID" AS number(10,0))) = ( CAST( "Extent6"."ID" AS number(10,0)))
            LEFT OUTER JOIN "STROY"."BUILD_INDICATOR_CLASSIFIER" "Extent7" ON ( CAST( "Filter1"."BUILD_INDICATOR_CLASSIFIER_ID" AS number(10,0))) = ( CAST( "Extent7"."ID" AS number(10,0)))
            LEFT OUTER JOIN "STROY"."FINANCING_SOURCE" "Extent8" ON (CASE WHEN ("Extent7"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent7"."FINANCING_SOURCE_ID" AS number(10,0)) END) = ( CAST( "Extent8"."ID" AS number(10,0)))
            WHERE ((( CAST( "Filter1"."YEAR" AS number(10,0))) >= :p__linq__0) AND (( CAST( "Filter1"."YEAR" AS number(10,0))) <= (:p__linq__1 + 4)) AND (CASE WHEN ("Extent4"."ID" IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE  CAST( "Extent4"."FINANCING_SOURCE_ID" AS number(10,0)) END IS NOT NULL))
        )  "Project1"
        GROUP BY "Project1"."C1", "Project1"."NAME", "Project1"."CREATE_DATE", "Project1"."DELETE_DATE", "Project1"."C2", "Project1"."C3", "Project1"."C4", "Project1"."C5", "Project1"."C6", "Project1"."C7", "Project1"."C8", "Project1"."C9", "Project1"."C10", "Project1"."C11", "Project1"."C12", "Project1"."C13", "Project1"."C14", "Project1"."C15", "Project1"."C16", "Project1"."C17", "Project1"."C18", "Project1"."C19", "Project1"."C20", "Project1"."C21", "Project1"."C22", "Project1"."C23", "Project1"."C24", "Project1"."C25", "Project1"."C26", "Project1"."C27", "Project1"."C28", "Project1"."C29", "Project1"."C30", "Project1"."C31", "Project1"."C32", "Project1"."C33", "Project1"."C34", "Project1"."C35", "Project1"."C36", "Project1"."C37", "Project1"."C38", "Project1"."C39", "Project1"."C40", "Project1"."C41", "Project1"."C42", "Project1"."C43", "Project1"."NAME1", "Project1"."CREATE_DATE1", "Project1"."DELETE_DATE1", "Project1"."C44", "Project1"."C45", "Project1"."C46", "Project1"."C47", "Project1"."C48", "Project1"."C49", "Project1"."C50", "Project1"."C51", "Project1"."C52", "Project1"."C53", "Project1"."C54", "Project1"."C55", "Project1"."C56", "Project1"."C57", "Project1"."C58", "Project1"."C59", "Project1"."C60", "Project1"."C61", "Project1"."C62", "Project1"."C63", "Project1"."C64", "Project1"."C65", "Project1"."C66", "Project1"."C67", "Project1"."C68", "Project1"."C69", "Project1"."C70", "Project1"."C71", "Project1"."C72", "Project1"."C73", "Project1"."C74", "Project1"."C75", "Project1"."C76", "Project1"."C77", "Project1"."C78", "Project1"."C79", "Project1"."C80", "Project1"."C81", "Project1"."C82", "Project1"."C83", "Project1"."C84", "Project1"."C85", "Project1"."NAME2", "Project1"."CREATE_DATE2", "Project1"."DELETE_DATE2", "Project1"."C86", "Project1"."C87", "Project1"."C88", "Project1"."C89", "Project1"."C90", "Project1"."C91", "Project1"."C92", "Project1"."C93", "Project1"."C94", "Project1"."C95", "Project1"."C96", "Project1"."C97", "Project1"."C98", "Project1"."C99", "Project1"."C100", "Project1"."C101", "Project1"."C102", "Project1"."C103", "Project1"."C104", "Project1"."C105", "Project1"."C106", "Project1"."C107", "Project1"."C108", "Project1"."C109", "Project1"."C110", "Project1"."C111", "Project1"."C112", "Project1"."C113", "Project1"."C114", "Project1"."C115", "Project1"."C116", "Project1"."C117", "Project1"."C118", "Project1"."C119", "Project1"."C120", "Project1"."C121", "Project1"."C122", "Project1"."C123", "Project1"."C124", "Project1"."C125", "Project1"."C126", "Project1"."C127"
    )  "GroupBy1"
)  "Project2"
ORDER BY "Project2"."NAME" ASC, "Project2"."NAME1" ASC, "Project2"."C2" ASC

How to simlify this query? It decreases free disk space on my virtual machine to zero very quickly.

Comment: Please format your question, it's unreadable.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work. I made the classes to test if it compiles. You probably have to adapt some things to your context but the interesting part is the `var sum = ...` part

```
class Title
{
    public int id;
}

class BuildIndicator
{
    public int id;
    public int titleId;
}

class BuildIndicatorValue
{
    public int id;
    public int buildIndicatorId;
    public int value;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var title = new Title();
    var buildIndicators = new BuildIndicator[5];
    var buildIndicatorValues = new BuildIndicatorValue[10];

    var sum = (from bi in buildIndicators
      join biv in buildIndicatorValues on bi.id equals biv.buildIndicatorId
      where bi.titleId == title.id
      select biv.value).Sum();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: Was just a missing parenthesis